# Form.Close() is closing other form (dialog) also

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a simple winforms application. The application starts with MainForm which is hidden all the time. MainForm opens another form called Notification (.Show) which closes after 10 seconds. So if the MainForm opens a dialog form (.ShowDialog) while Notification is still open, the open dialog also closes if Notification hits 10 seconds and closes.

The Notification form as well as the dialog form have `TopMost = True`

An example:

Short example:
The OtherDialogForm closes also even if my application only does this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Notification("Title", "Content").Show(); // closes itself after 10 seconds
        new OtherDialogForm().ShowDialog(); // being closed by form above (not wanted)
    }
}
```

Longer example:
MainForm.cs

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
    {
        base.SetVisibleCore(false);
    }

    public MainForm() 
    {
        CreateNotification();
    }

    public void CreateNotification()
    {
        new Notification.Show();
    }

    // triggered while Notification (from above) is still open
    private async void TriggeredByHotkey()
    {
        using (OtherDialogForm dialog = new OtherDialogForm())
        {
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            // if DialogResult == ...
        }
    }
}
```

Notification.cs

```
public partial class Notification : Form
{
    Timer timer;

    public Notification()
    {
        // sets timer tick to 10 seconds,
        // then calls void with this.Close()
    }

    // not sure if I really need this, but the problem is still there without
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 8;  // Turn on WS_EX_TOPMOST
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

I have really no idea why the dialog closes together with Notification.

Comment: A dialog needs an owner window.  If you don't provide one with the ShowDialog(owner) overload or Owner property then it goes looking for one by itself.  It will pick the active window that's owned by the same thread.  If you close or hide that window then the dialog is history as well.  Note how it won't be MainForm, even though you called ShowDialog() in its constructor, it is not active yet.   Otherwise trivially fixed by using ShowDialog(this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the Notification form instead of closing it, since is just a notification you do not really need to  close it, you can keep it in the background and show it when is needed.
From the msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

> This version of the ShowDialog method does not specify a form or control as its owner. When this version is called, the currently active window is made the owner of the dialog box. If you want to specify a specific owner, use the other version of this method.

So if you are using ShowDialog and the Notification form becomes the parent of the other dialig form, they both will be closed at closing Notification form

Comment: To specify it, this application is a client that uploads screenshots. So every time an image was uploaded a notification with a link appears but this is also not the only case a notification is needed. On a notebook for example this application could run several days so I don't know if it's good practice to keep so many forms in background and I'm also trying to keep the memory usage lower.

Comment: After your edit: Now it works! .ShowDialog(this) solved a problem I was searching for days. Thank you!

Comment: Try to use .ShowDialog(this) instead of the overload without parameters, it should work as you will make the main form the parent of the dialog one

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i am not a fast writer on the phone, I am glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are triggering the `TriggeredByHotkey` method from notification form. That method it'll be only running while your caller it's alive. Specially if you are reffering the Dialog with the `using`.

At the end of the method, the referred variable by `using`, calls it's own Dispose which will close the form.

Comment: `TriggeredByHotkey` is triggered inside of MainForm. Even if I call `Notification.Show()` and `OtherDialogForm.ShowDialog()` inside of `using` in only one method, the dialog is still closing after 10 seconds.