# WinForm window sometimes arbitrarily setting its DialogResult variable to Cancel immediately after ShowDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title says, I have a `WinForms` window that is sometimes setting its `DialogResult` property to `Cancel` immediately after `ShowDialog` is called.

The window is displayed like this:

```
bool isSuccess = (ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK);
```

Now most of the time, the `DialogResult` is set to `None` when the window is first instantiated, as it should be. In these cases, the window will remain open/active until the `DialogResult` is set to something other than `None`.

I have even changed this function to look like:

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None;
bool isSuccess = (ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK);
```

And still, sometimes, the `DialogResult` will immediately be `Cancel`.

There is no where in my code being hit that sets or interacts with the `DialogResult` property, anywhere, at any time, when it is automaticall set to `Cancel`.

Also if I break on the line immediately after `ShowDialog` is called, the entire stack trace leading up to the `ShowDialog` call is *identical* - line for line.

Given that nothing is actually interacting with the `DialogResult` property, I have absolutely no idea how to stop this.

Comment: Add an event handler for the FormClosing event and set a breakpoint on it.  The stack trace might give a hint.  Keep in mind that a dialog always automatically closes without your help if you hide it or its owner window disappears.

Comment: You can use ShowDialog with the overload that takes as parameter the form you want to become it's owner and see if you have the same behavior

Comment: I will test what the FormClosing event looks like, but it can take some time to reproduce the behaviour is it only happens about 10% of the time. And before anyone asks, no, nothing different is being done 10% or any % of the time.

Comment: We're just going to be playing guessing games. If you would like more help, please provide a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This isn't really an answerable question without that. I believe most of us who have done Windows Forms development for years can testify that it doesn't randomly change on its own. There's more going on somewhere with your code that we're not seeing here.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver Besides giving you the automatically generated code inside `InitializeComponent();`, I'm not sure what additional code would be of relevance here. There's a `Winform` window, you call `ShowDialog`, 10% of the time the `DialogResult` is arbitrarily set to `Cancel`. That's it, no more no less.

Comment: There's still something different. I can (and have) easily created an application which can open and close as many dialogs as I wish without encountering this behavior. The example you've given here isn't enough to reproduce your problem - this code on its own works as expected. As it is, this isn't really an answerable question without more context.

Comment: Well, ShowDialog is a method which called without any parameter takes the first form as owner, and when that form is closed, the form which is showed with this method closes itself too. What I suggest is making another form which you may show or not, but use it to invoke ShowDialog on the form you want to show as a dialog. This way you can set a owner for the form you want to show  as a dialog. You can find more information on this at msdn or an aparently similar case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775843/form-close-is-closing-other-form-dialog-also/37777237#37777237)

Comment: @Justin, there's only two options here. Either your code is wrong and you're just being impossible by not sharing enough of it to allow anyone to help you, or one of Microsoft's most popular libraries refuses to work with only your correctly written code. You seem to be convinced it's the second option, in which case, what do you expect from anyone here? Are you wanting someone to report a bug to Microsoft for you?

Comment: I was pretty much in the situation OP described. It took 2 people 4 hours to find out what was the reason. The reason was that the parent window closed, but it was not that obvious. We have the Main Window and a SplashScreen and we open a WinForms dialog WITHOUT SETTING AN OWNER for the dialog. Sometimes, the Main Window was the owner, sometimes, the SplashScreen was the owner. WinForms seems to set it automatically somehow. Our SplashScreen closes after some time which leads to a closed dialog when the SplashScreen is the owner. Hint: Set the owner of the dialog (if not already done)!

Answer (score 0):

How are you closing the window? If you close it using the X, the result is automatically set to DialogResult.Cancel (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx))

> When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close button (the button with an X in the top-right corner of the form) causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set to DialogResult.Cancel. The Close method is not automatically called when the user clicks the Close button of a dialog box or sets the value of the DialogResult property. Instead, the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box. Because of this behavior, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

EDIT:
If I'm understanding correctly, you also mention that it works correctly "when it's first instantiated". Does that mean you're re-using the same form after closing it? If so, this isn't supported. Once it is closed, you have to create a new instance of the form to show it again.

Comment: I think my question should be clear enough. I am NOT closing the window. I am calling `ShowDialog`, and then the window closes instantly, because the `DialogResult` property has sometimes set itself to `Cancel` magically.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your message where you mention that you're not closing the form yourself at all. There's something else going on - Windows Forms isn't "magical". If the window is closing, something is telling it to somewhere.

Comment: I would argue that it is most certainly magical, as the behaviour is only witnessed about 10-20% of the time, and the workflow/inputs to get to that point are _never_ different. In any case, were I closing the window myself, evidently I wouldn't have an issue...

Comment: Computer programs are never magical - they always do exactly what they're told in predictable ways. You have to start with the assumption that if your'e getting different behavior, it means there's a difference somewhere. You just have to identify what the difference is.

Comment: And yet I have evidence in front of me to the contrary! Anyway, perhaps the other people can help.

Comment: Also take a look at my edit - does this apply to you? It's hard to tell the specific scenario for sure.

Comment: No, I didn't say it works when it is first instantiated, I said that the majority of the time the `DialogResult` property is set correctly to `None` when it is instantiated. Some of the time it is set to `Cancel`, without reason. The window is "instantiated" on every usage of it.